# CPU usage going 100% after upgraded maria DB version from 10.2 to 10.6

Tags: symfony, mariadb, doctrine, amazon-rds, upgrade

I'm using CRM Symfony based application. I'm using AWS RDS Maria DB for the database from the last 2 years. Everything was working smoothly. But before 2 days I've upgraded Maria DB version (as it's mandatory) from 10.2 to 10.6.

After the upgrade, CPU usage went to 99% continue and the session increasing to 800. I've created a new parameter group for the 10.6 version. I didn't update anything in the code or query.

Please give your help/suggestion for the same.

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done deep research and finally got the solution.

https://conetix.com.au/support/slow-mariadb-sql-queries-in-statistics-state/

this is an option from MariaDB and Mysql that for each query it does some analysis so it updates it in the next queries, but the complex queries stay too long analyzing instead of actually do the query and we can have queries that were taking too long to execute and put everything on hold and hanging.